# What probems may arise with a 200V rated relay conducting 1000V 1A?

Tags: relay, switch-mode-power-supply

I am going to use a DPST relay to pass a 1A 1000V DC signal of an ESD Human Body Model simulator circuit through it.

I have see many relays, they share a property like maximum DC switching for example 200V (and it is generally higher for AC like 400).

Now my question is, If I get a relay that has 200V DC switching property what kind of problems I will get?

Or can I do like this: I will control the signal and also the relay using a micro controller, so I can be sure that I first turn ON the relay then start the signal. I believe the relay should just work like a shorting wire and cause no problems? Same case also for switching the relay OFF that is I first stop the signal and then turn OFF the relay. Is this approach going to work?

Comment: What kind of signal is that, at 1A 1000V?

Comment: It is a signal coming from a ESD Human Body Model simulator circut I want to make. it discharges a 150pF Capacitor with 1000V

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is what happens when you try to disconnect a relay at a high voltage relative to the dielectric strength of the medium (air)/open air gap.

During the brief period when the gap is opening, but not yet fully open, the air gap looks like a capacitor.  The dielectric strength of air, that is, the amount of voltage needed to turn it from an insulator into a conductor, isn't terribly great.

If there is any inductance in the circuit, current will continue to flow into the gap, momentarily charging the capacitor up far past the dielectric strength of the air.  Almost all contact style switches produce some amount of spark.  You may have noticed the wall switches in your house flash when you turn off large loads.

That spark is cause by the ionization of the air, turned into a plasma, that happened to carry a few electrons across the gap.  Though air is a decent insulator, plasma is a very good conductor.  As current flows through the plasma, more plasma is produced.  The rate of plasma production will basically be determined by the voltage across the gap (more voltage is more current is more plasma), and the resistance of the plasma (less resistance is more current is more plasma).

If the gap is large compared to the voltage, the plasma will quickly dissipate, and the switch will do it's job of opening the circuit.  If the voltage is large, compared to the gap, the volume plasma will increase faster than it can dissapate, until the whole gap is filled with plasma, and conducting electricity in a run-away reaction.

If you're lucky, that's the worst of it.  If the contacts are metallic (and they usually are at modest voltages), the intense heat of the plasma can cause the contacts to melt and ultimately *weld closed*, putting the switch in a perminantly on state, even after current is removed.

A similar process can occur even in solid state switches;  This is not a phenomenon limited to mechanical relays.

You should *NEVER* use a switch to open a circuit at a voltage higher than the value it is rated to block.  Fortunately, high voltage, [solid state](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/STMicroelectronics/STGF3NC120HD/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMtvcUztdGSumGWBIWhLr08tF8O2aJQLh70=) switches are perfectly capable and available at reasonable cost.

Comment: I like this description!

Comment: Another thing that's worth noting is that when switching inductive loads, *even when there are flyback diodes*, the current through the contacts won't drop as fast as when switching a resistive load.  A relay switching a resistive load will have its contacts separated by a certain distance before the voltage between the contacts reaches the supply voltage.  With an inductive load, the voltage will reach the supply voltage sooner.  Flyback diodes may prevent the voltage across the contacts from exceeding the supply voltage, but flyback diodes may not stop the contacts from "drawing" an arc.

Answer (score 8):

First I would NOT try to pass a 1000V signal through a relay rated for 200V.  When closed you *may* not have a problem (absolutely no guarantees), but when OPEN it may arc and, well, that would be bad.  Suffice it to say it would not exactly act as an open in that circumstance.

Second, I realize you said that the signal wouldn't be there when the relay is open - you'd turn it on after the relay is closed and off after the signal is turned off.  If you already have that control over the signal why use a relay?  To switch between two different destinations?  In that case you'll still have the arcing problem.

A datasheet would help if you want a better answer.